# Чтение двумерного массива из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Необходимо написать программу, считывающую двумерный массив из файла, название которого вводится в консоль с клавиатуры, и выводящие считанный массив на экран.
Помогите найти ошибку

> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>   int i, j;
>   FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
>   if ((in) == NULL)
>   {
>       printf("Cannot open file.\n");
>   }
>   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
>   {
>       for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
>       {
>           fscanf(in, "%d", &A[i][j]);
>           printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
>       }
>       printf("\n");
>   }
>   getchar();
>   return(0);
> }
> ```
>
> P.S. Вопрос решен

Comment: @Андрей Габриелян, пожалуйста:

- во-первых в вопросе обязательно пишите в **чем именно заключается ошибка** (сообщения компилятора, программа падает, ожидал один результат, а вижу другое и приводите текст, который Вы видите (ну, мы же тут программеры, а не фокусники-телепаты));

- во-вторых не меняйте ошибочный текст программы на правильный в тексте вопроса (это очень сбивает), добавляйте исправления в новом тексте в конце вопроса;

- в-третьих приводите в тексте вопроса (в коде) также все определения переменных, относящиеся к этому коду (у Вас, например, массив `A[][]` в вопросе не описан).

Answer (score 1):

```
...
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, j;
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
...
```

Вот так нужно.
`char** argv` вместо `char* argv` и `fopen(argv[1], "rt")` вместо `fopen(&argv[1], "rt")`

Comment: К счастью, проблему решил самостоятельно. После argv нужно поставить [] а в fopen убрать &перед ним же и все будет в шоколаде. Но все равно спасибо =).
Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Собственно, тоже что я и написал.